# Solving act() warnings in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my components and the tests are passing, however I keep getting act warnings about pieces of state that are updating in my terminal:
" Warning: An update to Bird inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).  "

The warning is referring to the  `const handleRemoveBird = () => { setShowModal(true); };` state update.

Is this something so do with the state being linked to the Modal component and it's updating outside of the test? If that's the case (or not), what do I need to await/waitFor to fix the act warning?

My test:

```
import { screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { renderWithProviders } from "../utils/utils-for-tests";
import Bird from "../components/Bird";

const modalContainerMock = document.createElement("div");
modalContainerMock.setAttribute("class", "modal-container");
document.body.appendChild(modalContainerMock);

const birdImgMock = jest.mock("../../components/BirdImg", () => {
  return () => {
    return "Bird Img Component";
  };
});

const renderComponent = (bird) => {
  renderWithProviders(<Bird bird={bird} />);
};

const bird = {
  id: "1",
  name: "blue tit",
  number: "5",
};

test("shows modal before removal", async () => {
  renderComponent(bird);
  const removeButton = await screen.findByTestId(`removeButton-${bird.id}`);
  expect(removeButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  user.click(removeButton);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId("modal")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
...
```

My component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { RxCross2 } from "react-icons/rx";
import { useRemoveBirdMutation } from "../store";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import Button from "./Button";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Sightings from "./Sightings";
import BirdImg from "./BirdImg";

function Bird({ bird }) {
  const [removeBird, removeBirdResults] = useRemoveBirdMutation();
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleRemoveBird = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };
  const handleDelete = () => {
    removeBird(bird);
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const actionBar = (
    <>
      <Button primary onClick={handleClose}>
        Keep
      </Button>

      <Button secondary onClick={handleDelete}>
        Delete
      </Button>
    </>
  );

  const modal = (
    <Modal actionBar={actionBar} onClose={handleClose}>
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete this bird?</p>
    </Modal>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Panel
        primary
        data-testid="bird"
        key={bird.id}
        className="grid grid-cols-5 md:gap-5"
      >
        <div className="col-span-2">
          <BirdImg name={bird.name} />
        </div>

        <div className="col-span-2 grid content-around -ml-4 md:-ml-8">
          <h4 className="capitalize text-lg font-bold md:text-3xl ">
            {bird.name}
          </h4>
          <div>
            <Sightings bird={bird} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 justify-self-end">
          <Button
            onClick={handleRemoveBird}
            remove
            loading={removeBirdResults.isLoading}
            data-testid={`removeButton-${bird.id}`}
          >
            <RxCross2 />
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Panel>
      {showModal && modal}
    </>
  );
}
export default Bird;
```

Comment: Hmm, I would have though the `waitFor` solves this problem. Have you tried with `findBy` instead of `getBy` for the modal?

Comment: @Arkellys yep, I've tried both of those solutions but unfortunately I still get the warning. After some trial and error it seems if I manually wrap the `user.click(removeButton);` in act() the warning disappears. I'm aware that's not best practice though...

Comment: Are you sure the act warning comes from this test and not another one?

Comment: Ah I think you might be right @Arkellys , thanks for pointing that out! That state update affects how the Modal component acts, I guess that could be causing the act warning. Not entirely sure how to solve that issue in the test, mocking maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "That state update affects how the Modal component act"? On the code you shared the only thing happening would be the modal appearing, which should be covered with the `waitFor`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean @Arkellys , yeah I worded that badly. Hmm I was thinking that since the state updates whether the modal appears it could be affecting the re-usable Modal component as it's updating with the props passed to it? That might be completely wrong though

Comment: Hmm I suppose that's possible, but I have not used RTL for a while now. I suppose the best way to test this would be to replace the modal with a dummy component and see. But that will not solve your issue... these warnings drove me crazy for months before I finally understood how to avoid them. xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one solution that works for me, you probably need to wrap the click event inside `waitFor`.

```
test("shows modal before removal", async () => {
  renderComponent(bird);
  const removeButton = await screen.findByTestId(`removeButton-${bird.id}`);
  expect(removeButton).toBeInTheDocument();

  await waitFor(async () => {
    await user.click(removeButton);
  });

  expect(screen.getByTestId("modal")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly! The second `async` was the key, I had tried using `waitFor` previously and it hadn't worked but addition of the `async` gets rid for the act() warning and the test runs smoothly, Thank you!